# How to change array properties within a class from member function

Tags: php, arrays, class

In the code below, I'm trying to alter the $widget_ops "classname" array, based on the value of the $line_above variable in the "widget" function. I'm not sure how to address the array to change the value.

Is this possible?

```
class my_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function my_widget() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'test', 'description' => __( "test") );
        $control_ops = array('width' => 450, 'height' => 100, 'id_base' => 'my_widget' );
        $this->WP_Widget('my_widget', __('Test: test'), $widget_ops, $control_ops);
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance );
        $text = apply_filters( 'widget_text', $instance['text'], $instance );
        $line_above = isset( $instance['line_above'] ) ? $instance['line_above'] : false;

        if($line_above){
            //TRYING TO ALTER THE CLASS HERE BASED ON VARIABLE
            $widget_ops['classname'] .= " border-top";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it global:

```
class my_widget extends WP_Widget {

    private $widget_ops;

    function my_widget() {
        $this->widget_ops = array('classname' => 'test', 'description' => __( "test") );
        $control_ops = array('width' => 450, 'height' => 100, 'id_base' => 'my_widget' );
        $this->WP_Widget('my_widget', __('Test: test'), $this->widget_ops, $control_ops);
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance );
        $text = apply_filters( 'widget_text', $instance['text'], $instance );
        $line_above = isset( $instance['line_above'] ) ? $instance['line_above'] : false;

        if($line_above){
            //TRYING TO ALTER THE CLASS HERE BASED ON VARIABLE
            $this->widget_ops['classname'] .= " border-top";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you're providing is incorrect. By adding the line "private $widget_ops", you're adding a *property* to the class, which should be addressed; $this->widget_ops and can only be accessed from within the class itself (because its *"visibility"* is private)

Comment: Oops, missed that. Thanks.